# Linear Algebra and Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been working through my linear algebra notes today and asked myself a question that I do not know the answer to. My intuition says 'yes' but I can't seem to prove it.

Suppose I have three subspaces $W_{1},W_{2},W_{3}$ with trivial intersection $W_{i}\cap W_{j}= \left \{  \boldsymbol{0} \right \}$.

Suppose that I know that $ax+by \in W_{1}$ for some scalars $a,b$. Assume that $x,y$ are elements which belong to either of the three subspaces.

Then do I necessarily have that $x,y \in W_{1}$?

My guess would be 'yes' but I can't seem to think about this rigorously. Is this given already by the closure property of a subspace?

Comment: What are you assuming about $x$ and $y$? You never say. Please edit the question.

Comment: I assume that $x,y$ are elements that belong to either of the three subspaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no.

Take $\mathbb{R}^2$ as your total space and define $$W_1 = \{(x,0) : x \in \mathbb{R}\},$$ $$W_2 = \{(x,x) : x \in \mathbb{R}\},$$ $$W_3 = \{(0,x) : x \in \mathbb{R}\}.$$ It is clear that $W_{i}\cap W_{j}= \left \{  \boldsymbol{0} \right \}$ and $$ \frac{1}{2}(0,-1)+ \frac{1}{2}(0,1) \in W_1$$ but $(0,-1) \notin W_1.$

Comment: This example proves me wrong. I understand now that I cannot make this assumption without further conditions. I'll mark this answer as correct!